# How to check if the user didnt input any value in prompt box in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, input, prompt

What can I use to know if there was no input in a prompt? Already tried the < "" > but doesnt seem to work for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the [response text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getResponseText()) is an empty string:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Enter your name:');
console.log(response.getResponseText()=="")
```

if `response.getResponseText()==""` is `true`, it means there was no input given.